# The same expression but different result

Tags: c++

So I am doing a question in leetcode. It is Implement Stack using Queues.
If I submit this code below. It is accepted.

```
class Stack {
    public:
    queue<int> que;
    // Push element x onto stack.
    void push(int x) {
        que.push(x);
        for(int i=0;i<que.size()-1;i++){
            que.push(que.front());
            que.pop();
        }
    }

    // Removes the element on top of the stack.
    void pop() {
        que.pop();
    }

    // Get the top element.
    int top() {
        return que.front();
    }

    // Return whether the stack is empty.
    bool empty() {
        return que.empty();
    }
};
```

but if I only change `for(int i=0;i<que.size()-1;++i)` to `for(int i=0;i<=que.size()-2;i++)`, I got Time limitation exceeded. Last executed input: push(1),empty().Could somebody tell me why??? Thanks

Comment: What happen if `que.size()` = 1? (hint - nothing good)

Comment: they are not the same expression

Comment: In that case, it will not enter the loop, which is the right thing to do.@BoBTFish

Comment: `que.size()-2` is an unsigned value, so it will be a very large positive number if `que.size() == 1`

Comment: Could you explain why they are not the same??@tobi303

Comment: @LinJing But `que.size()` returns you an **unsigned** integer type.

Comment: `unsigned` – anything = `unsigned`

Comment: @LinJing The two expressions are clearly different. You even say "if I only change...". If you change one of them, the second is not the same. That `-1`->`-2` matters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`queue::size()` returns a size_t which is basically an unsigned number. and a *negative unsigned number* converts to a huge number.

So `queue::size()-1` --> huge number (0xFFFFFFFF)

Comment: It returns a `queue::size_type`, but I'm just being pedantic.